# C# can't add to list before Update() runs in XNA

Tags: c#, xna, collision-detection

I have 4 classes; *Main*, *Map*, *Player*, and *Cam*. I have *Map* making the map and calculating the co-ordinates of the map. *Player* is calculating the co-ordinates and hit boxes of the player. For some reason, I cannot get *Main* to read a list in *Map* because when I run the program, it tells me there is nothing in the list - except I know that is untrue. I think Update() is simply trying to read the list before *Map* has a chance to add things to the list. At run time, it gives me an index error - how can I fix this?

Here are parts of the classes that are part of my problem:

*Main*

```
Player player = new player();
Map map = new Map();
Texture2D world;    

protected override void LoadContent() {
    //load a bunch of textures and stuff here
    world = this.Content.Load<Texture2D>("world");
    map.CalculateMap(world);
}

protected override void Update(GameTime gameTime) {
    if(player.Collision()) {
        velocity = 0.0f;
    }
}
```

*Player*

```
Map map = new Map();
public void Collision() {
    if(map.metalRect[3].Intersects(charRect)) { //metalRect[3] DOES exist
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

*Map*

```
public List<Rectangle> metalRect = new List<Rectangle>();
public void CalculateMap(Texture2D world) {
    //add a bunch of stuff to metalRect
}
```

Comment: Is that all the relevant code in your Player class, as nowhere is the `CalculateMap` method being called prior to checking metalRect[3]?

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I've updated it.

Comment: It looks like Player is using a different map (`new Map()` above Collision) is this the case? Does the players constructor set the correct map reference?

Comment: At first glance, you're newing up map in the player instance, so you're not passing through your pre-configured map into player. Basically, pass your higher scoped map into player or make it available some other way.